# Qt access violation 0xC0000005 after slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have an issue that i just figured out what to do, so maybe you can help me.

I am working on a application that connects to a database, displays the values and allowes the user to update/insert values.

I have a `QTabView` and inside one of the tabs there are four `QTableWidget`'s.
Inside this Tables is sometimes (depends on the value of the database) a `QComboBox` to select some predefined Values.
I catch the `QComboBox::selectedIndexChanged(int)` with a `QSignalMapper` and have a `slot` connected to the `QSignalMapper` to give some information what table it was and what setting was changed. From time to time i create the SettingsMapper new (and delete it before that) to reset the 'outdated' mapper-combobox connections.

So the problem is, that when i change the index inside a combobox, the slot gets called and i can debug into the moc_*.cpp where the switch of the signal/slot connections is, but after that i get the `access violation on address 0xC0000005` inside the dlls.

Here the call stack:

```
QtCored4.dll!6721af70()     
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for QtCored4.dll]  
QtCored4.dll!67219fe5()     
QtCored4.dll!67218f14()     
QtCored4.dll!67218e48()     
QtCored4.dll!6721903d()     
QtCored4.dll!6720f874()     
QtCored4.dll!6702429b()     
QtCored4.dll!670316f3()     
QtGuid4.dll!655b93f1()  
QtGuid4.dll!650f99d0()  
user32.dll!7e41885a()   
user32.dll!7e41882a()   
user32.dll!7e42b326()   
msctf.dll!7472467f()    
user32.dll!7e43e1ad()   
user32.dll!7e43e18a()   
QtCored4.dll!67234b9c()     
user32.dll!7e42b372()   
user32.dll!7e418734()   
user32.dll!7e418816()   
user32.dll!7e4189cd()   
user32.dll!7e418a10()   
QtCored4.dll!672359b6()     
ntdll.dll!7c90cfdc()    
ntdll.dll!7c958e0d()    
ntdll.dll!7c95932a()    
ntdll.dll!7c90cfdc()    
ntdll.dll!7c9594ca()    
ntdll.dll!7c919ca7()    
ntdll.dll!7c918f01()    
ntdll.dll!7c91925d()    
ntdll.dll!7c918f01()    
ntdll.dll!7c9101bb()    
ntdll.dll!7c9192ef()    
ntdll.dll!7c918f01()    
ntdll.dll!7c9101bb()    
user32.dll!7e4277b0()   
user32.dll!7e4277f7()   
ntdll.dll!7c90da0c()    
kernel32.dll!7c8024c7()     
msctf.dll!74725951()    
msctf.dll!74725956()    
user32.dll!7e418a80()   
user32.dll!7e418734()   
user32.dll!7e418816()   
ntdll.dll!7c96c6a7()    
QtCored4.dll!6723c8f6()     
datProgram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 578 + 0x35 bytes   C
datProgram.exe.exe!WinMainCRTStartup()  Line 403    C
kernel32.dll!7c817067()
```

`

What makes me curios is, that in another tab is one `QTableWidget` with the same methods as described above, but the problem does not occur there.
And when running in release version(Ctrl+F5) the problem also seems to be gone ... ò.Ó

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From time to time i create the SettingsMapper 
>   new (and delete it before that) to reset 
>   the 'outdated' mapper-combobox connections.

Do you by any chance delete the signal mapper from a slot called by signal sent from that signal mapper? That's not allowed, can't delete the instance when you are currently in a method of that instance.

Solution is to use deleteLater() instead. That will cause the object to be deleted when control returns to event loop.

Comment: wow you made me think twice it that could be possible ... i'll check and tell you whats going on

edit: will the `QObject::deleteLater()` also work on the `QSharedPointer<QSignalMapper>`when i use its `operator=` too?

Comment: thanks man, as it looks it does not seem to work on the shared pointer but i changed it in a simple `QSignalMapper*` and it works fine. :D

Comment: @Zaiborg With smart pointers, it's important to understand the rules of the exact smart pointer class used. Generally with QObjects with a parent, if a smart pointer is really needed, then a `QPointer` or `QWeakPointer` should be used, they can handle the QObject getting deleted elsewhere. And when having a QObject without parent, one should always ask, if not having a parent is really the right way to go in that case (because it's really convenient to have parent make sure it is deleted properly).